# SQL Query for executing a series of update statements

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, unix

I have a set of update statements which needs to be executed one after the other. The database that i am using is Oracle and i am running these queries by connecting to the database using a shell script. What i want to know here is to how i could execute these commands one after the other only if the previous update statement is successful. The auto update is set to OFF in the shell script and i want to commit all the statements only when all of them are executed successfully else i want to exit. Is there a way to run these update commands one after the other by checking the preceding queries status and commit after all the queries are run successfully.

Comment: Are you using Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: use if else block

Comment: It is oracle DB

Comment: update * from table_name where condition;

Comment: update * from table_name where condition;update * from table_name where condition;update * from table_name where condition;update * from table_name where condition;update * from table_name where condition;

Comment: can i get a code snippet on how to execute the above queries

Comment: a the beginning of the sql script specify: WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT ROLLBACK
In case of any error during the SQL execution a rollback will occur, you can safely commit at the end of the updates because it means no error occured during the execution.

Answer (score 2):

you can use WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT ROLLBACK:

```
sqlplus -s username/password@network-name <<EOF
   WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT ROLLBACK
   update table1 set mycolumn=value where mycolumn=1;
   update table1 set mycolumn=othervalue where mycolumn=2;
   update table1 set mycolumn=othervalue where mycolumn=3;
   update table1 set mycolumn=othervalue where mycolumn=4;
   commit;
   exit
EOF
```

Here is a link to the documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve052.htm

Comment: This is exactly what i am looking for. Thanks mate :)

Comment: great ! consider accepting the answer if it resolved your problem.